# Finding enumerable properties more directly

Tags: javascript

I have the following which iterates through an object/array to print its enumerable properties:

```js
const reg = /(?<num>hi)(there)/g;
const str = 'hithere';
let matches = Array.from(str.matchAll(reg)); // same thing as [...matches[;]]
for (let match of matches) {
    for (let elem of match) {
        console.log('**', elem);
    }
}
```

The actual object looks like this:

```
  [
    'hithere'.   // enumerable
    'hi',        // enumerable
    'there',     // enumerable
    index: 0,                                      // no
    input: 'hithere',                              // no
    groups: [Object: null prototype] { num: 'hi' } // no
  ], ...
```

Is there a more direct way to (1) get the enumerable properties in an object; or (2) test to see if an Object property is enumerable? I thought the following would work but it seems to always print `true` for me:

```
matches[0].propertyIsEnumerable('index'));
```

Comment: Within your Array, you say you'll have a key value pair, like for example, index: 0 . Are you saying { index: 0 }  ?

Answer (score 0):

That's a very good question.

for ... of does not necessarily loop over all enumerable properties in an object the way that for ... in does.  Javascript objects can define their own [iterable protocol](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Iteration_protocols).

The booleans your getting from propertyIsEnumerable are correct.

So to answer your questions directly:
(1) yes: a for... in loop
(2) no: your test is working fine

```js
const reg = /(?<num>hi)(there)/g;
const str = 'hithere';
let matches = Array.from(str.matchAll(reg)); // same thing as [...matches[;]]
for (let match in matches) {
    for (let elem in matches[match]) {
        console.log(elem, matches[match][elem]);
    }
}
```